# JSON + chartkick in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, chartkick

I'm trying to set up chartkick for my project, but recently I started running into issues - page where I have several of my charts won't load (chrome offers to kill it after a few minutes of trying to load). I'm still not sure what's exact issue, but I narrowed it down to charts and decided to try change how they are loaded from basic method I've been using so far

```
<%= pie_chart @articles.where(:tag => 'test').group(:category).count %>
```

to JSON method mentioned on chartkick's webpage, but it doesn't seen to work for me.

Here's what I have in my files:

*articles_controller.erb*

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
[...]
  def cat_en
    render json: @articles.where(:tag => 'test').group(:category).count.chart_json
  end
[...]
[private section goes below]
end
```

*index.html.erb*

```
<%= pie_chart cat_en_articles_path %>
```

and I keep getting error:

```
 undefined local variable or method `cat_en_articles_path' for #<#<Class:0x5fe4910>:0x604efc0>
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Did you include `cat_en` method under private? If so move that method above `private` and try.

Comment: No, it's not in private, it's above.